# How to Set Price on SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, decimal

[You can see sql here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pyv3.png)
I've a form on a website and when I add the price in this format -> "199.99", it's saving "1999.00" on SQL. And the same problem with "19.99" format.

Table type is "Decimal" and "10.2". How can I save price format "19.99".

INPUT:

```
<input name="price" type="text" id="price" class="form-control"  placeholder="0.00" onkeyup="calculate()" required />
```

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: Try examining the actual SQL command.

Comment: Your localisation settings are giving the problem. "." is seen as a thousand separator, not as the decimal point!

Comment: @noobdoez could you provide more details regarding your table ? show us the output of describe tablename;.

Comment: I added image please view

Answer (score 0):

Its your code, not sql

> Block quote

Comment: i added please can you view?

Comment: My guess is adding two strings instead of two numbers ? Try <input type='number

Comment: If i change input type "number" i cant add "." or "," :/

Comment: <input name="price" type="number" step="any" 'id="price" class="form-control"  placeholder="0.00" onkeyup="calculate()" required />

Comment: @NoobDoez did it work ?